# Google Map in Plugin WP GPX Maps not showing up

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need you help. I use the Plugin WP GPX MAPS together with another google map (integrated in sabai google maps) plugin.  unfortunately the map of WP GPX maps is not showing up because of  "a javascript error that is telling there are 2 instances of Google Maps API being loaded"

I have already searched for a solution in stackoverflow and found out that I have to add this code line
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
in  my js file wp-gpx-maps.js https://github.com/wp-plugins/wp-gpx-maps/blob/master/WP-GPX-Maps.js
but I do not know if this is right and where in wp-gpx-maps.js I have to include this line.
can you pls. help me and point out in which line I have to put google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize"); 
thank you very much!

See Problem here https://www.tourendatenbank.com/touren/gipfel/gangolfsberg

Answer (score 0):

it's only a compatibility problem with your tab plugin.

this is your code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var sabai_wpgpxmaps = function() {
        <<wp-gpx-maps code>>
    };
    if (jQuery("#sabai-inline-content-wpgpxmaps").is(":visible")) {
        sabai_wpgpxmaps();
    } else {
        jQuery("#sabai-inline-content-wpgpxmaps-trigger").on("shown.bs.sabaitab", function(e, data){
            sabai_wpgpxmaps();
        });
    }
});
```

the function sabai_wpgpxmaps is never been called